# Extract information in a line of text with a format from user input

Tags: python, bash, format

I am trying to make a program which takes in input song files and a format to write metatags in file. Here is a few examples of the call:

- `./parser '%n_-_%t.mp3' 01_-_Respect.mp3` gives me `track=01; title=Respect`
- `./parser '%b._%n.%t.mp3' The_Queen_of_Soul._01.Respect.mp3` gives me `album=The_Queen_of_Sould; track=01; title=Respect`
- `./parser '%a-%b._%n.%t.mp3' Aretha_Franklin-The_Queen_of_Soul._01.Respect.mp3` gives me `artist=Aretha_Franklin; track=01; title=Respect`
- `./parser '%a_-_%b_-_%n_-_%t.mp3' Aretha_Franklin_-_The_Queen_of_Soul_-_01_-_Respect.mp3` gives me `artist=Aretha_Franklin; track=01; title=Respect`

For a call on the file `01_-_Respect.mp3`, I'd like to have a variable containing `01`, and the other `Respect`.

Here `%n` and `%t` represents respectively the number and the title of the songs. The problem is that I don't know how to extract this information in bash (or eventually in python).

My biggest problem is that I don't know the format in advance!

**Note:** There is more information than this, for example `%b` for the album, `%a` for the artist etc.

Comment: Take a look at he [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html). Especiallay at the `sys.argv` part.

Comment: I may have not been clear. My problem is not to access the program arguments. It is to extract from `01_Respect.mp3` the variables  `track_number=01` and `title=Respect` with the user defined format `%n_-_%t.mp3`

Comment: so you need regex support?

Comment: Maybe, I don't know if the regex can help me here because the format is peculiar (not conforming to a regex) and there is multiple things to extract in the same line.

Comment: Should the first argument be regex compliant? Or is it given to you in that format? In other words: Can you yourself define how the first argument looks like?

Comment: It is given to me in that format so unfortunately, I can't define how the first argument looks like.

Comment: Ok, read that too late...

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use the string method `split` to split the string by `_-_`.

and for taking the input from the command line, you can use sys.argv to get that.

here's an example:

```
import sys
number,title = sys.argv[1].split("_-_")
```

**Update:**

Surely you can pass the pattern as a first argument and the file as the second argument like that:

```
import sys
pattern = sys.argv[1]
number,title = sys.argv[2].split(pattern)
```

Now if you need more complex and dynamic processing, then `Regex` is your winning card!

And in order to write a good regex, you got to understand your data and your problem or you'll end up writing a glitchy regex

Comment: Still, the format (first argument) could be anything. My solution is also not perfect regarding that. Your solution is more readable, though. I like it.

Comment: @onda47 you can replace `_-_` in the code with whatever the format you have, for example: `sys.argv[1].split("._")`

Comment: So your solution includes to go through the line, detect a pattern which split the two fields and manage an index to find at what index is the field? I was expecting a bit more elegant solution ^^

Comment: @onda47
Then you should have clarified that in your question that you don't know what could be the pattern, because what I have understood is that you have a fixed pattern

Answer (score 0):

You can elaborate on this. It is a very simple example, though.

```
import re
p = re.compile('([0-1][0-1])_\-_(.*)\.mp3')
title = '01_-_Respect.mp3'
p.findall(title)
```

Output
    `[('01', 'Respect')]`

I use this [page](https://regexr.com/) to play with regex.

**Update**

Since the format is given, go with string slicing. Ok, pretty limited to the specific case..

```
number = title[:title.find('_')]
>>> number
'01'
>>> track = title[len(number) + 3:len(title)-4]
>>> track
'Respect'
```

Comment: What if the user inputs `%n_____.______%a.mp3`? Here we don't have title, what is between fields is not given in advance.

Comment: Then use the above code and check for `%n` and `%t`, in order to get what you want. Provided `%n` and `%t` are always in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try This code:

(considering argument is given in runtime)

```
tmp=$1
num=echo ${tmp%%_*}
title=echo ${tmp##*_}|cut -d. -f1
```

Variables num and title will store the parts from the argument