# Split a line with matching regex special characters

Tags: python, regex, split

Currently I want to split a line with all the matching special characters of the regex. As it is hard to explain, here are a few examples:

`('.+abcd[0-9]+\.mp3', 'Aabcd09.mp3')` -> `[ 'A', '09' ]`

- `.+` is a special expression of the regex and this is the match that I want
- `[0-9]+` is another regex expression and I want what it matches too

`('.+\..+_[0-9]+\.mp3', 'A.abcd_09.mp3')` -> `[ 'A', 'abcd', '09' ]`

- `.+` is the first special expression of the regex, it matches `A`
- `.+` is the second special expression of the regex, it matches `abcd`
- `[0-9]+` is the third special expression of the regex, it matches `09`

Do you know how to achieve this? I didn't find anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract information in a line of text with a format from user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48401402/extract-information-in-a-line-of-text-with-a-format-from-user-input)

Comment: Your question is unclear, please, edit it and add test cases with expected result.

Comment: is it clear enough now? Otherwise, precise what you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a so called [tokenizer/lexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) to parse a regular expression first. It will allow you to split a base regex on sub-expressions. Then just apply these sub-expressions to the original string and print out matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = ['Aabcd09.mp3', 'A.abcd_09.mp3']
new_s = [re.findall('(?<=^)[a-zA-Z]|(?<=\.)[a-zA-Z]+(?=_)|\d+(?=\.mp3)', i) for i in s]
```

Output:

```
[['A', '09'], ['A', 'abcd', '09']]
```